# Java code to read excel on Mac

Tags: java, macos, file, path

I have been trying to read excel using java code but i am not sure what should be the excel path. This is what i am using on mac:

```
String xPath = "Desktop/ReadData.xls".
```

I am getting error message `"No such file found"`

How the path should be given on mac?

Please help guys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the desktop, then the path must be specified relative to the current user's home directory, like this:

```
/Users/<user>/Desktop/ReadData.xls
```

Where `<user>` is your user name in the Mac. Or alternatively, you can use this shorter form:

```
~/Desktop/ReadData.xls
```